# How to install Zarafa on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: mail-server

Does anybody know a got tutorial explaining how to install Zarafa on Ubuntu 11.10? Or does anybody know a good alternative? I would really like to have a easy administrable System providing all my thousands of mail on a local machine, making me able to access them both with standard email client like Thunderbird and via a good web interface. Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zarafa doesnt provide packages for 11.10, but only for the Ubuntu LTS versions. The only way to run Zarafa on 11.10 would be to compile the packages yourself (that would be the opposite of easy).

For administrating your server you should take a look at Z-Admin (https://community.zarafa.com/pg/plugins/project/672/developer/zarq/zadmin) its an recently as final published web control panel from the Zarafa Community. There is also a pre built Ubuntu VMWare Image.